# getting extjs and cakephp associated models to work together

Tags: cakephp, extjs

When I do a `find('all')` in cakephp with model associations, the format the data is returned in is similar to this:

```
{
    data: [
        {
            'mainModel': {},
            'associatedModel1': {},
            'associatedModel2': {},
            'associatedModel3': {},
            'associatedModel4': {}
        },
        {
            'mainModel': {},
            'associatedModel1': {},
            'associatedModel2': {},
            'associatedModel3': {},
            'associatedModel4': {}
        }
    ]
}
```

when I write a store in ExtJS, I would need to set the record config option to `mainModel`, but then how would the associations work? As far as I can tell,  extjs would expect the data to be formatted like so:

```
{
    data: [
        {
            'mainModel': {
                'associatedModel1': {},
                'associatedModel2': {},
                'associatedModel3': {},
                'associatedModel4': {}
            }
        },
        {
            'mainModel': {
                'associatedModel1': {},
                'associatedModel2': {},
                'associatedModel3': {},
                'associatedModel4': {}
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

am I correct in understanding this? How can I get ExtJS and CakePHP to play nicely with each other? Am I forced to manipulate the data to fit to ExtJS' liking?

Comment: possible duplicate of [format cakephp find result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10975733/format-cakephp-find-result)