# format cakephp find result

Tags: cakephp, model, formatting

If I do a `mainModel->find('all')` call on a model, my data is returned in this format:

```
[
    {
        'mainModel': {},
        'associatedModel1': {},
        'associatedModel2': {},
        'associatedModel3': {},
        'associatedModel4': {}
    },
    {
        'mainModel': {},
        'associatedModel1': {},
        'associatedModel2': {},
        'associatedModel3': {},
        'associatedModel4': {}
    }
]
```

how can i get it to return in this format:

```
[
    {
        'mainModel': {
            'associatedModel1': {},
            'associatedModel2': {},
            'associatedModel3': {},
            'associatedModel4': {}
        }
    },
    {
        'mainModel': {
            'associatedModel1': {},
            'associatedModel2': {},
            'associatedModel3': {},
            'associatedModel4': {}
        }
    }
]
```

please excuse my object-notation formatting. I find JSON to be the prettiest way to explain data structures.

Answer (score 1):

You can't alter the format that data is returned from in a find, but you CAN mangle the format after it's been returned. Check out the Set library: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/set.html

The burning question is, WHY do you want to change the structure? CakePHP expects data in this structure and if you start changing it, your app will break in unexpected/hard to track down ways...

Comment: because extjs doesn't like this format for it's own models and associations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10975454/getting-extjs-and-cakephp-associated-models-to-work-together also, I know about set, but how would I use it to achieve the format i'm looking for?

Comment: Sorry. I'm no Set guru. If it gets complicated I write a helper routine to mangle formats. This may be your best bet. Wrap it in a helper and then in your view: echo $this->Extjs->format($data)